# Create SQL function referring to a table or column that does not exist (yet)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql, sql-function

I want to load some SQL functions in a empty database through psql:

```
psql -d my_database -f fuctions.sql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

I use `--set ON_ERROR_STOP=1` because I want that psql fails if the script contains errors.

The content of `functions.sql` is:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS INT AS $$
  SELECT id from test_table;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

My problem is, that psql checks if `test_table` exists when loading function and fails with this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "test_table" does not exist LINE 2: SELECT id from test_table;
> ```

But I don't want that psql check if the table exists because I will create this table later.

Following workarounds would work but I cannot use them:

- Ignore errors. I want psql to exit with an error if the script contains i.e. sql syntax errors.
- Use plpgsql functions instead of sql. Of course I could, but simple sql functions are often the best choice.
- Create the table first. My real scenario is actually more complex than this example.

Comment: Do you know the names of the affected tables (and the corresponding functions) in advance ( := before they even exist) ?

Comment: You could use a table as *application catalog* where the tables (and functions) are registered. With triggers on this table you could automate the generation of the actual functions (replacing the stub-functions) and maybe even the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message comes from Postgres, not from psql.

#### Workaround

If you cannot create the table first (for what ever reason), you could **"fake it until you make it"**: Create a temporary table with matching structure. You only need column names and types to match. For your example function:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_table (id int);
```

Then `CREATE FUNCTION` goes through. Dropping the table later is not prohibited. Postgres does not save dependencies for code in the function body. So you can drop the table once the function is created. If you call the function after dropping the temp table, you get an error.

After you create the actual table later, the function will work normally.

#### Disable parsing of SQL function at creation time?

To my knowledge, this is **not possible**. Maybe there is a compile-time option for Postgres to disable it. [The manual advises to use PL/PgSQL for cases like yours](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html):

> **Note:** The entire body of a SQL function is parsed before any of it is
>   executed. While a SQL function can contain commands that alter the
>   system catalogs (e.g., `CREATE TABLE`), the effects of such commands
>   will not be visible during parse analysis of later commands in the
>   function. Thus, for example, `CREATE TABLE foo (...); INSERT INTO foo VALUES(...);` will not work as desired if packaged up into a single SQL
>   function, **since `foo` won't exist yet when the `INSERT` command is parsed**.
>   It's **recommended to use PL/PgSQL instead** of a SQL function in this
>   type of situation.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: I have actually a big number of scripts and functions and I don't want to check the database schema in every function. I hoped there is a simple option in psql (or inside the sql function?) which tells to postgres 'do not check the schema!'

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico: I wouldn't know of any option to suppress parsing during function creation. I added quote and link to the manual.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, I will use pl/pgsql instead of sql procedures.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the configuration variable `check_function_bodies` to false before creating the functions.

For instance, this should let you create your test function even though `test_table` doesn't exist:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL check_function_bodies TO FALSE;
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS INT AS $$
  SELECT id from test_table;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
COMMIT;
```

Documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CHECK-FUNCTION-BODIES

Comment: Is it possible to force a re-check once all functions/tables are in place? similar to Oracle's "compile"?

Comment: Is there any equivalent in mssql?

Answer (score 0):

You could split up yur sql-file e.g. into DDL, DML and then executing the functions.

So something like

file1:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id int primary key,
   data int);
```

file2:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS INT AS $$
  SELECT id from test_table;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
....
```

And then calling psql something like

```
psql -f file1 
psql -f file2
psql -f ....
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot create the table first. My real scenario is actually more compex than this example.