# Continue a PL/pgSQL block even if it finds an error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've gotten the essence of the function below from: [How to re-check an SQL function created with check_function_bodies=false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422768/how-to-re-check-an-sql-function-created-with-check-function-bodies-false)

The context is: I'm migrating some functions from Oracle to PostgreSQL. While migrating them, I used the option which establishes a non-verification of their bodies, so that all function could be created without being compiled/verified, what would "speed" the process. Therefore, now - using the function bellow as a mean - I am trying to make an analysis of each function created in this X schema.

My problem is that the function doesn't continue when it finds an error. My central thought is to run the `recompile_function()` once and get all the messages fired when an error is found for each function. I have tried to enclosure the statement that verifies the function within a sub-block (BEGIN, EXCEPTION, END). It didn't work though.

What am I missing here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.recompile_functions()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$function$
DECLARE
    l_func regprocedure;
BEGIN
    --test plpgsql functions
    FOR l_func IN (
        SELECT oid
        FROM pg_proc
        WHERE pronamespace='<<schema>>'::regnamespace
        AND prolang=(SELECT oid FROM pg_language WHERE lanname='plpgsql')
        AND pg_proc.oid NOT IN (select tg.tgfoid FROM pg_trigger tg)
        AND pg_proc.prokind = 'f'
    ) 
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            PERFORM plpgsql_validator(l_func);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Function % failed validation checks: %', l_func::text, SQLERRM;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$
```

Comment: When you catch an exception you raise another one. Replace `RAISE EXCEPTION` with `RAISE NOTICE` or add some code to log the error message.

Comment: Since you are not actually returning anything you could use a `procedure` instead of a `function` and use [Transaction management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html).

Comment: When you do `raise exception ...` within an exception block the raised exception propagates to the next higher level exception block. Since you do not have a higher level exception block it propagates all the way out and terminates. Rather than `raise exception` you should use `raise notice` or `raise log` or another [raise level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE)l which would not terminate the process,